# SQL convert rows generated by CTE to columns - including fieldnames

Tags: sql-server, pivot, common-table-expression

I have a CTE that generates data into a variable number of rows. These are hourly values that I need to use in a join to another table, but that part is not important here.

The CTE part alone looks like this:

```
DECLARE @interval INT = 3 -- hours
DECLARE @period INT = 24 -- hours
;WITH cteHour AS (
    SELECT CAST('i0' AS VARCHAR(6)) AS fieldname, 0 AS i, 0 AS startpos
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT('i', CAST(i + 1 AS VARCHAR(5))) AS fieldname, i + 1 AS i, startpos + @interval AS startpos
    FROM cteHour
    WHERE (startpos + @interval) < @period
) SELECT fieldname, startpos FROM cteHour
```

And it generates data like this (depending on the `@interval` and `@period` values):

```
fieldname startpos
--------- -----------
i0        0
i1        3
i2        6
i3        9
i4        12
i5        15
i6        18
i7        21
```

My question is how can I get the results into columns instead of rows, using the first column as the field names, like this:

```
i0 i1 i2 i3 i4 i5 i6 i7
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
0  3  6  9  12 15 18 21
```

I'm guessing it will require a `PIVOT`, but as far as I know pivoting cannot generate field names dynamically. So I'm open to any answers that get the job done.

Comment: since the `@interval` and `@period` is dynamic, you will required to use `Dynamic SQL`. You might need to re-think how this is going to work in your complete solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simplest answer using a dynamic query

```
DECLARE @interval INT = 3 -- hours
DECLARE @period INT = 24 -- hours
DECLARE @startpos INT = 0
DECLARE @i INT = 0
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT '
WHILE @startpos < @period
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + (CASE WHEN @i > 0 THEN ',' ELSE '' END) +
    CAST(@startpos AS VARCHAR(5)) + ' AS i' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(5))

    SET @i = @i + 1
    SET @startpos = @startpos + @interval
END
print @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it required a dynamic sql, skip the pivot part and straight away generate the dynamic query from your cte

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @sql    = isnull(@sql + ',', 'select ')
                + quotename(fieldname) + '=' + convert(varchar(10), startpos)
FROM    cteHour
order by startpos 

print   @sql

exec    sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do what you want, it uses a temp table but you'd get an idea on how the approach is

```
DECLARE @interval INT = 3 -- hours
DECLARE @period INT = 24 -- hours
;WITH cteHour AS (
    SELECT CAST('i0' AS VARCHAR(6)) AS fieldname, 0 AS i, 0 AS startpos
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT('i', CAST(i + 1 AS VARCHAR(5))) AS fieldname, i + 1 AS i, startpos + @interval AS startpos
    FROM cteHour
    WHERE (startpos + @interval) < @period
)

SELECT * INTO #temp FROM cteHour;

DECLARE @pvt NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SET @pvt = STUFF(
  (SELECT DISTINCT N', ' + QUOTENAME([fieldname]) FROM #temp FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,N'')

EXEC (N'SELECT *
            FROM #temp
        PIVOT (MAX([startpos]) FOR [fieldname] IN('+@pvt+')) AS PIV');
```